# Favicon not displayed despite correct image size, format and path

Tags: html, css, pixel, favicon

My favicon is not working. Below is my current code but I have also tried `<link rel="icon" href="pngeckfavicon.png" type="image/png" >`  and a variety of other combinations. The images are both 16x16 but I have also tried it with a 32x32 version of both.
Both the eckfavicon.ico file and the pngeckfavicon.png file are in the root folder (and not in a subfolder like "images"). Why is my favicon still not working?

Thank you so much for your help :)

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" > 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>LUCA</title>
<link href="eckstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="eckfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" >
</head>
```

Comment: What is your file structure?

Comment: @HarryTom Favicon file is in the same folder as all my HTML files for this website :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```html
 <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="eckfavicon.ico">
```

[More About Favicon](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_favicon.asp)